# Replace (temporarlily) a function from JS file to one modified from the client browser

Tags: javascript, angular

Suppose I have an Angular application that performs calculations between different parameters. The number of parameters can change, as well as the relations between.

To simplify, say users operates with 3 parameters fill-in `A`, `B` to obtain `X` and `Y`, having the formulas `X = A + B` and `Y = A * X`.

The application has one js file per calculated parameter. In that case `A` and `B` are filled in by user, and `X` and `Y` - calculated.

`x.js`

```
export function X(A: number, B: number): number {
    return A + B;
}
```

`y.js`

```
export function Y(A: number, X: number): number {
    return A * X;
}
```

The formulas are supposed to change over time. So I would like to let some special users to be able to modify the formula, and then preview/test the result.

A user could then load a js formula, modify it, and try it. In that mode, the `function X()`  should not be loaded from the `x.js` file, but from the user modified text in editor.

My question is if there is a way to temporarily replace a JS function used by angular from a js file with some js code modified by user in the browser. That behavior should not affect other web application users.

Comment: You'll probably need to use `eval()` or `Function()` to convert user input into JS executable code. Beware of the security issues. See: https://www.educative.io/edpresso/eval-vs-function-in-javascript

Comment: @KamilChlebek, the problem is not only to convert, but also to replace the existing function

Comment: Think in this way, you don't even need an "existing function", just make a default value of the "user input".

Comment: btw using `eval()` is not safe and not recommended. You may want to come up with some data structure to represent a formula.

Answer (score 0):

It greatly depends on how you declare your functions.

But yes, it's possible.

All you need to have is a way to access your function. It must NOT be global (i.e. you have to call it with, for instance, `window.myFunction`).

Here is an example :

```js
window.myFn = (a, b) => a + b;

console.log('Original function : ' + window.myFn(2, 3));

const symbol = window.myFn;

window.myFn = (a, b) => a * b;

console.log('Changed function : ' + window.myFn(2, 3));

window.myFn = (a, b, c) => symbol(a, b) * c;

console.log('Extended function : ' + window.myFn(2, 3, 4));
```

Note that you will have many context issues depending on how you wrote your functions, for instance in Angular, something like this

```js
export class Component {
  myFn() {}
}
```

Should be overwritten like this

```js
export class Component {

  constructor() { window.myFn = this.myFn.bind(this); }

  myFn() {}
}
```